# DRF, How to parse the data of the model

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the following model and serializer:

```py
#models.py

areas = [
    ('210', '210'),
    ('769', '769'),
    ('300', '300')
]


class LocationInfo(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField(name='GDT 1 Latitude',
                                 unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                 help_text="Enter the location's Latitude, first when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                 default=1)
    longitude = models.FloatField(name='GDT 1 Longitude',
                                  unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                  help_text="Enter the location's Longitude, second when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                  default=1)
    gdt2_lat = models.FloatField(name='GDT 2 Latitude',
                                 unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                 help_text="Enter the location's Latitude, first when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                 default=1)
    gdt2_lon = models.FloatField(name='GDT 2 longitude',
                                 unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                 help_text="Enter the location's Latitude, first when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                 default=1)
    uav_lat = models.FloatField(name='UAV Latitude',
                                unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                help_text="Enter the location's Latitude, first when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                default=1)
    uav_lon = models.FloatField(name='UAV longitude',
                                unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                help_text="Enter the location's Latitude, first when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                default=1)

    uav_elevation = models.FloatField(name='UAV Elevation', max_length=100, default=1)

    area = models.CharField(
        max_length=8,
        choices=areas,
    )

    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

```py
# serializers.py

from .models import LocationInfo
from rest_framework import serializers


class LocationInfoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LocationInfo
        fields = (
            'id', 'GDT 1 Latitude', 'GDT 1 Longitude',
            'GDT 2 Latitude', 'GDT 2 longitude',
            'UAV Latitude', 'UAV longitude', 'UAV Elevation',
            'area', 'date_added')
```

I want to get only the last object created and parse it as a JSON file, so I can manipulate that data and then return a response.
I don't get how can I access said data, reading it in JSON format will allow me to apply my logic function on the data.

```py
# views.py

class LocationInfoViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = LocationInfo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LocationInfoSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven' tested this, but Im quite sure you can change your query set from `.all()` to `.latest('date_added')`

like this:

```
class LatestLocationInfoViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = LocationInfo.objects.latest('date_added')
    serializer_class = LocationInfoSerializer
```

here is the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest)